# ¿Como configurar proyecto laravel en Servidor VPS ubuntu?

Tags: laravel-5, ubuntu

Actualmente tengo alojado un proyecto laravel en un servidor vps en la siguiente ruta **"/var/www/html"**
pero tengo el inconveniente que solo cuando ingreso a la direccion ip es decir:
http://direccion_ip/ me muestra el index de apache2 que es el que viene por default al tener realizada la configuracion del servidor.

Entonces para acceder a mi proyecto laravel lo debo hacer de la siguiente forma: **http://direccion_ip/proyecto_laravel/public** de esta forma ingresa al proyecto.

mi consulta es:
¿Como hago para que al ingresar solo a la ip **http://direccion_ip/** ingrese por default ya al proyecto laravel que tengo configurado?.

Segun tengo entendido debo ingresar al archivo **httpd.conf**, pero en mi caso unicamente aparece el archivo **apache2.conf**

Por favor si alguien pudiera ayudarme para realizar esta configuracion, de antemano muy agradecido.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tienes que editar el archivo `000-default.conf` ubicado en `/etc/apache2/sites-available`, buscar `DocumentRoot` y cambiar la direccion que aparece al lado.

Ejemplo: `DocumentRoot /La/Ubicacion/Del/Proyecto`

Luego necesitaras reiniciar apache: `sudo service apache2 restart`

En caso de que te genere un error, deberas editar `apache2.conf` ubicado en `/etc/apache2` y buscar algo similar a esto

```
<Directory />
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all denied
</Directory>
```

Y dentro de el modificar la linea de `Options` agregandole `Includes ExecCGI`, dicha deberia quedar asi.

```
<Directory />
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
    AllowOverride All
    Require all denied
</Directory>
```

Un poco fuera del tema, pero realmente necesitas cambiar el directorio por defecto? porque puedes mover o copiar temporalmente tu carpeta, con los comandos `mv`para mover o `cp` para copiar, eliminar el contenido de var/www/html con el comando`rm`

Ejemplo

```
$ mv var/www/html/proyecto_lavarel ~/Desktop
$ sudo rm -rf /var/www/html/*
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, me ha funcionado. Solo que no te entendi eso ultimo que me preguntas, acerca de cambiar el directorio por defecto. No entiendo perdon.
Muchas gracias por tu ayuda.

Comment: Me refería, a que es mas fácil eliminar los archivos dentro de www y reemplazarlos con los archivos de tu proyecto :P

Comment: ah bueno.  Tengo el siguiente inconveniente, si pudieras ayudarme porfavor.
En esta aplicacion de larave consumo los WebService del mismo, por ejemplo **http://direccion_ip/proyecto_laravel/public/ws/colaboradores**, pero ahora me sale "not found the requested url" ya ejecute ** sudo a2enmod rewrite**, pero nada.

Comment: Creo que es un problema con Virtual Host sigo estos pasos: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/como-configurar-virtual-hosts-de-apache-en-ubuntu-16-04-es pero no me funciona